# Where to write code for intent when ill navigate from child activity to parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities. One is child of another. 
ActivityA is parent, ActivityB is child.
So, when ill navigate to the ActivityA from ActivityB using the ActionBar- i want to put some data in intent using putExtra. Where to write the code?

Comment: While starting the activity you can put extra.

Comment: OnStart of ActivityB? but i want the intent to receive from ActivityA too.

Comment: you can override the onBackPressed Method

Comment: best way use shared preference in both activity and update the values

Answer (score 0):

You can declare intent's under any of the methods like `onCreate()`, `onOptionsItemSelected` or even in your own custom method. The only thing required is that you **need to extend the Activity** class. Call intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

Also do not forget to mention your Activities in the manifest.

like this:

```
<activity name=".ActivityB"/>
```